# Excel-vba compare, condition, delete

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file with activities for different colleagues, like so:

- 1 jan 2016 || 1 dec 2016 || 100% || colleague A
- 1 feb 2014 || 31 dec 2014 || 100% || colleague B
- 1 jan 2016 || 1 okt 2016 || 100% || colleague B
- 1 okt 2016 || 31 dec 2016 || 80% || colleague B
- 1 nov 2016 || 10 dec 2016 || 100% | colleague B
- 1 dec 2016 || 1 jan 2017 || 50% || colleague B

Start date || end date || usage % || colleague

Now what I would like is to see what people are working on now / when they are available for what % / since when they have been available.

So deleting rows which end date is in the past, unless that is the only row for a colleague, because then I want to see that row as a measure of " since when has he been available for a new job ".

But then colleague B for example, has several things going. How would I go about removing old stuff but keeping the two lines that he;s working on now + the line that he will be working on as of 1 dec?

They can have a usage % of >!00 thats fine.

Sorry for the long description... Im not looking for code, just the psuedo code / logic to tackle this!

Comment: Ok will edit, obviously just typed the sample lines from the top of my head. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Im not looking for code, just the psuedo code / logic

It seems to me that you just need the following:

1. A simple loop to go through each row and look at the end date.
2. If the end date is in the past, then go to step 3.
3. If the employee has only one record, do not delete, otherwise go to step 4.
4. If end date is in the past, **and** there is more than one record - delete.

> How would I go about removing old stuff but keeping the two lines that he;s working on now + the line that he will be working on as of 1 dec?

I believe simply testing if the end date is in the past will suffice for each scenario?

---

In pseudo code that might look like:

```
For i = [num_rows]
    If end_date < today Then
        If [COUNTIF(colleague_column, colleague)] > 1 Then
            rows(i).delete
        End If
    End If
Next
```

or

```
For i = [num_rows]
    If end_date < today And [COUNTIF(colleague_column, colleague)] > 1Then
            rows(i).delete
    End If
Next
```

---

or in *actual* VBA (we would loop backwards in the case of deleting rows) assuming your data is in columns A:D with no headers:

```
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If CDate(Cells(i, 2)) < Date And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D:D"), Cells(i, 4).Value) > 1 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting. Your answer was just right. My code came out like this:

http://pastebin.com/zaSPb4v1

I couldn't paste the code in this comment due to character limitations...

By the way, the shift-up seems to be unnecessary as it already does just that - shift cells up.

Comment: Almost forgot to say thanks! So, thanks! Marked your reply as the correct answer.

Comment: Not a problem. :)